# Postgres transaction mode to ignores / allows errors when resolved inside the transaction

Tags: postgresql

Is there a Postgres transaction mode that ignores / allows errors within the transaction as long as they end up being fixed inside the transaction?

For example let's say I have to tables: `a` and `b`.
`a` has a foreign key on `b` *but* `b` is created after `a`.
I know I can simply create both table and then run `alter table` to create the foreign key. But that's not the approach im looking for.

Example sql:

```
create table a (
  a_id int,
  b_id int,

  primary key(a_id),
  constraint foreign key(b_id) references b(b_id)
)
create table b (
  b_id int,

  primary key(b_id),
)
```

Comment: There is no way to do that. You will have to fix your statements.

Comment: This is what deferring constraints does. However, that only works for DML with your own data, not for DDL statements - schema constraints such as only referencing existing tables are not deferrrable.

Comment: @Bergi thank you, that was the hint i was searching for

Answer (score -1):

You have two variants:

1. Firstly create table b after than create table a
2. Create table a without a foreign key, after then create table b and after then add a foreign key to table a.

Example:

```
create table a (
  a_id int,
  b_id int,
  primary key(a_id)
);

create table b (
  b_id int,
  primary key(b_id)
);

alter table a 
add constraint fk1 foreign key(b_id) references b(b_id);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's exactly what I'm aware of and don't want to do as described in the question.